Reserved IP ranges for Vertex AI pipelines in GCP
Can anyone explain what the "reserved_ip_ranges" parameter is in the GCP Vertex AI Pipeline job? From this doc: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.PipelineJob#google_cloud_aiplatform_PipelineJob_submit
I have a shared vpc, peering with servicenetworking-googleapis-com (a project owned by gcp where my pipelines run), and several allocated IP ranges for this peering. But how to use specific IP address ranges in a Vertex AI Pipeline job?

Hi @Oleksandr Lytvynskyi, This documentation explains the process of using shared VPC network and Reserved IP ranges. Let me know if this helps you or not

Reserved IP Range name is used for VPC Peering.
The subnetwork allocation will use the range name if it's assigned.
Example: managed-notebooks-range-c
PEERING_RANGE_NAME_3=managed-notebooks-range-c
gcloud compute addresses create $PEERING_RANGE_NAME_3 \
  --global \
  --prefix-length=24 \
  --description="Google Cloud Managed Notebooks Range 24 c" \
  --network=$NETWORK \
  --addresses=192.168.0.0 \
  --purpose=VPC_PEERING

Example: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Databases/Unable-to-create-PostGRE-SQL-db-with-Private-IP/m-p/655122/highlight/true

Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have 3 ranges that were reserved this way, but when I specify the range name in the job parameters, I get the error "Internal error occurred for the current attempt." and "Internal error occurred. Please retry in a few minutes. If you still experience errors, contact Cloud AI Platform."

Update for previous comment: the Pipeline service account has the Network User role.
